# plot heatmap of data after clustering in R

Tags: r, heatmap, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to create a heatmap of a matrix after clustering.

```
heatmap(r.matrix, 
        distfun = dist(r.matrix, method="euclidean"), 
        hclustfun = hclust(dist(r.matrix, method="euclidean"), method ="ward"))
```

I used the above command following help message of heatmap, but came back with the following error message:

```
Error in heatmap(r.matrix, distfun = dist(r.matrix, method = "euclidean"),  :
                 could not find function "hclustfun"
```

How can I do a clustering, and draw a heatmap of the clustered data, also keep the dendrogram? I might have not understood the functions in the argument list well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `distfun` and `hclustfun` arguments are supposed to be functions. You're passing the *results* of those functions, and since the results aren't themselves functions, the error is thrown. You know how `apply`, for example, wants a function as its third argument? Then it calls that function itself? `heatmap` is the same way.

Try this:

```
heatmap(r.matrix, distfun=dist, hclustfun=function(d) hclust(d, method="ward"))
```

Actually, since `dist` is the default argument (see `?heatmap`), you can omit `distfun` from the function call. The only reason you have to create an anonymous function for `hclust` is because the default method is not "ward".

```
heatmap(r.matrix, hclustfun=function(d) hclust(d, method="ward"))
```